# Wordpress Plesk real cron job - not running every 15 min

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, plesk

I went through few articles explaining how to setup real cron job on Wordpress - it works just not in the way I want.

I want to run it every 15 min (0,15,30,45) but it runs only at 15 min past every hour.

Command I am running: `wget -q -O - http://staging.deathnotices.co/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron >/dev/null 2>&1`

Cron Style: `0,15,30,45 * * * *`

All is on Plesk.

I did disable WP_CRON

Any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: what do the logs say? `tail -f /etc/syslog | grep cron`

Comment: I don't have access to ssh unfortunately

Comment: There is a terminal, presumably browser based, in plesk. https://www.astutium.com/tutorials/watch.php?id=77&series=4&format=text

Comment: If there is then I dont have access to it either...

Comment: I found a way to access logs - and it all seems to be fine. Every 15 min my command is running without any errors - but message is sent only at 15min past every hour...